# Nested React Router doesn't update layout

Tags: reactjs, routes, nested, router

App component with Root routes:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Routes from './routes';

class App extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Routes/>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Root routes:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Login from './scenes/Login/Login';
import Dashboard from './scenes/Dashboard/Dashboard';

const Routes = () => (
    <Router>
        <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Login} />
            <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
);

export default Routes;
```

Nested component with nested routes:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from '../../logo.png';
import './Dashboard.css';
import Routes from './routes';
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class Dashboard extends Component {

    render() {        

        return (
            <div className="App">
                <div id="map" />
                <div className='sidebar'>
                    <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
                    <Link to={{ pathname: `/dashboard/profile` }}>
                        <i class="icon blue fa fa-2x fa-user mr-3 float-right"></i>
                    </Link>
                    <Link to={{ pathname: `/dashboard/notifications` }}>
                        <i class="icon blue fa fa-2x fa-bell mr-3 float-right"></i>
                    </Link>
                    <Link to={{ pathname: `/dashboard/home` }}>
                        <i class="icon blue fa fa-2x fa-home mr-3 float-right"></i>
                    </Link>
                    <Routes />


                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

Nested routes:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Notifications from './scenes/Notifications/Notifications';
import Home from './scenes/Home/Home';
import Profile from './scenes/Profile/Profile';

const Routes = () => (
    <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/dashboard/home" component={Home} />
            <Route path="/dashboard/profile" component={Profile} />
            <Route path="/dashboard/notifications" component={Notifications} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>
);

export default Routes;
```

So the problem is that when I click the Link ex.(`/dashboard/notifications`) it changes the url in the browser but doesn't update the layout but when I refresh the page it works fine and the proper components are visible. The `/` route and `dashboard` works fine.

Comment: Take a look at **withRouter** function in [documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter)

Comment: Isn’t it only for redux? Im not using redux here.

Answer (score 1):

I may be a little late, but passing the location to the switch solved my issue.

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  useLocation
} from "react-router-dom";

let location = useLocation();
```

and inside the render:

```
<Router>
  <Switch location={location}>
    <Route path="/dashboard/home" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/dashboard/profile" component={Profile} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use NavLink tag instead of Link and BrowserRouter instead of Router , import it from "react-router-dom"

Comment: I have  edited my response, and also try to change pathname with to="/.." inside the NavLik , this is how react router v4 work

Comment: And the problem could not be because your are referencing to the same stateless functional components Routes, see your imports, you are using only one of 2 declared ! I think this is your problem, you are importing the same one (this first) in your two components

Comment: Would you explain more what exactly should i do please?

Comment: Of course, first of all, to be sure taht this is the problem, in dashboard component, try to put directly your routes inside the switch tag instead of importing it in from Routes tag, ( pute directly the contents of Routes that contains the tree inner routes inside dashbord compoent) and tell me if it works

Answer (score 0):

use this method of link syntax

```
 <Link to='/dashboard/notifications'>
                    <i class="icon blue fa fa-2x fa-bell mr-3 float-right"></i>
                </Link>
```

instead of this

```
 <Link to={{ pathname: `/dashboard/notifications` }}>
                        <i class="icon blue fa fa-2x fa-bell mr-3 float-right"></i>
                    </Link>
```

if it dosn't work it may something with your browser caching or some other problems